# ASP.Net textbox has empty text property, but browser displays the right value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Update: Found the issue. text property is using the old value from the aspx file. It doesn't consider the attribute change during post back. Now, how to solve that problem is a different thing.

Original question: 
I have a textbox in my page, where I display a value on page load, depending on the requested record.

```
<ASP:TEXTBOX id="txtWarrantyNoValue" runat="server" CssClass="LabelTextBox" ReadOnly="True"></ASP:TEXTBOX>
```

On page load, based on the query string, I set the text property, which works perfectly. But, on postback, value of `txtWarrantyNoValue.Text` is empty string. I am unable to figure out why this is happening at all.

Edit:

```
        protected void Page_Load( object sender, System.EventArgs e )   {

        try {

            if ( Request.QueryString[ "MESSAGE" ] != null && Request.QueryString[ "MESSAGE" ] != "" )   objErrorDisplay.MessageCode = Request.QueryString[ "MESSAGE" ];

            string  strWarrCommData = Request.QueryString[ Constants.QS_DATA_FLAG ];

            if ( strWarrCommData != null && strWarrCommData.Trim().Equals( Constants.QS_COMMISSION_DATA ) ) bWarrantyScreen = false;


            strScreenMode =  Request.QueryString[ Constants.SESSION_MODE ];

            if ( strScreenMode == null )    strScreenMode = Constants.SCREEN_MODE_MODIFY;
            if ( strScreenMode == "" )      strScreenMode = Constants.SCREEN_MODE_MODIFY;

            hdnScreenMode.Value = strScreenMode;

            ApplyPermissions();

            Localize();

            BindDropDowns();

            if ( !IsPostBack && strScreenMode != Constants.SCREEN_MODE_NEW )    this.GetWarrantyContractData();             

            SetControlStyleByScreenMode();

        }
        catch ( FANUCBaseException fbeEx )  {
            objErrorDisplay.ErrorToLog = fbeEx;
        }
    }


        private void BindDropDowns()    {

        this.ddlSalesType.Attributes.Add( "DataSource", "DefaultDataIslands" );
        this.ddlSalesType.Attributes.Add( "DataMember", Constants.DI_SALES_TYPE );
        this.ddlSalesType.Attributes.Add( "IsBlankReqd", "Y" );
        this.ddlSalesType.Attributes.Add( "SelectedValue", Request.Form[ "ddlSalesType" ] );

        this.ddlCurrency.Attributes.Add( "DataSource", "DefaultDataIslands" );
        this.ddlCurrency.Attributes.Add( "DataMember", Constants.DI_CURRENCY_CODE );
        this.ddlCurrency.Attributes.Add( "IsBlankReqd", "Y" );
        this.ddlCurrency.Attributes.Add( "SelectedValue",Request.Form[ "ddlCurrency" ] );
    }

Function to get the data
virtual public Row[] GetWarrantyContract( Row objWarrantyFilter, FANUC.Common.BaseClasses.PagingEventArgs e )   {

        string  strSqlQuery 
            = " SELECT"
            + " WRNT_Warranty_No," 
            + " WRNT_Seiban," 
            + " WRNT_HQ_Seiban," 
            + " CASE"
            + " WHEN WRNT_Data_Flag = '1' then 'Warranty'"
            + " WHEN WRNT_Data_Flag = '2' then 'Commission'"
            + " ELSE ''"
            + " END  AS WRNT_Data_Flag," 
            + " WRNT_Data_Flag as WRNT_Data_Flag_Value,"
            + " WRNT_Unique_Key," 
            + " CASE"
            + " WHEN WRNT_IM_Flag = 'I' then 'Installation'" 
            + " WHEN WRNT_IM_Flag = 'M' then 'Maintenance'"
            + " WHEN WRNT_IM_Flag = 'X' then 'Completed'"
            + " ELSE ''"
            + " END  AS WRNT_IM_Flag," 
            + " WRNT_IM_Flag as WRNT_IM_Flag_Value,"
            + " WRNT_System_OS_No," 
            + " WRNT_Entry_Seiban_Date," 
            + " WRNT_Warranty_Print_Date," 
            + " WRNT_MTB_Code,"
            + " WRNT_MTB_Name," 
            + " WRNT_Product_ID," 
            + " WRNT_Product_Name," 
            + " WRNT_Product_Serial_No_FA," 
            + " WRNT_Product_Serial_No_ROBO," 
            + " WRNT_Dealer_ID," 
            + " WRNT_Dealer_Name," 
            + " WRNT_End_Cust_ID,"
            + " WRNT_End_Cust_Name," 
            + " WRNT_Total_Amount," 
            + " WRNT_POS_No," 
            + " WRNT_Spec," 
            + " WRNT_Sales_Divide_No," 
            + " WRNT_Sales_Type," 
            + " WRNT_Shipped_Date," 
            + " WRNT_Commission_Fee," 
            + " WRNT_Commission_Rate," 
            + " WRNT_Without_Tax_Fee," 
            + " WRNT_Tax_Fee," 
            + " WRNT_Tax_Rate," 
            + " WRNT_Actual_Destination," 
            + " WRNT_Sales_Group_Code," 
            + " WRNT_Sales_Group_Name," 
            + " WRNT_HQ_To_Country," 
            + " WRNT_HQ_Destination," 
            + " WRNT_Invoiced_Flag," 
            + " WRNT_Invoive_No," 
            + " WRNT_Invoice_Date," 
            + " WRNT_Warranty_Start_Date," 
            + " WRNT_Warranty_End_Date," 
            + " WRNT_Local_Sale_Flag," 
            + " WRNT_Currency_Code,"
            + " WRNT_Seiban_Code,"
            + " WRNT_Comments,"
            + " Use_Count,"
            + " WRNT_Deferred_Revenues_Generated_Flag,"
            + " WRNT_CreatedDate "
            + " FROM"
            + " TBL_Warranty";

        Row objFilter   = new Row();

        objFilter[ "WRNT_Warranty_No~like" ]                = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_Warranty_No" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_Seiban~like" ]                     = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_Seiban" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_Entry_Seiban_Date~>=*_From" ]      = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_Entry_Seiban_Date_From" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_Entry_Seiban_Date~<=*_To" ]        = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_Entry_Seiban_Date_To" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_End_Cust_Name~like" ]              = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_End_Cust_Name" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_Warranty_Print_Date~>=*_From" ]    = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_Warranty_Print_Date_From" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_Warranty_Print_Date~<=*_To" ]      = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_Warranty_Print_Date_To" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_Warranty_End_Date~>=*_From" ]      = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_Warranty_End_Date_From" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_Warranty_End_Date~<=*_To" ]        = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_Warranty_End_Date_To" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_MTB_Name~like" ]                   = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_MTB_Name" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_Product_ID~like" ]                 = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_Product_ID" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_HQ_Destination~like" ]             = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_HQ_Destination" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_Total_Amount" ]                    = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_Total_Amount" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_Product_Serial_No_ROBO~like" ]     = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_Product_Serial_No_ROBO" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_Product_Serial_No_FA~like" ]       = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_Product_Serial_No_FA" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_Invoiced_Flag" ]                   = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_Invoiced_Flag" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_Local_Sale_Flag" ]                 = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_Local_Sale_Flag" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_Data_Flag" ]                       = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_Data_Flag" ];
        objFilter[ "WRNT_HQ_Seiban~like" ]                  = objWarrantyFilter[ "WRNT_HQ_Seiban" ];


        CommonBQ    objCommonBQ         = new CommonBQ();
        string      strSearchClause     = objCommonBQ.CreateFilter( objFilter );
        int         iWarrantyFromIndex  = strSearchClause.IndexOf( "WRNT_Warranty_End_Date_From" );
        int         iWarrantyToIndex    = strSearchClause.IndexOf( "WRNT_Warranty_End_Date_To" );

        if ( iWarrantyFromIndex != -1 && iWarrantyToIndex == -1 )   {

            int iWarrantyEndSpaceIndex  = strSearchClause.IndexOf( " ", iWarrantyFromIndex );

            strSearchClause = strSearchClause.Substring( 0, iWarrantyEndSpaceIndex ) + " OR WRNT_Warranty_End_Date IS NULL " + strSearchClause.Substring( iWarrantyEndSpaceIndex + 1 ) ;                
        }


        string  strCountQuery   = " SELECT COUNT( 1 ) FROM TBL_Warranty";


        string  strFinalString  = "";
        string  strConnector    = " WHERE ";

        if ( !strSearchClause.Equals( "" ) )    {

            strFinalString  = strSqlQuery + strConnector + strSearchClause ;

            strCountQuery   += strConnector + strSearchClause ;
        }
        else    {

            strSqlQuery     += strConnector ;

            int     iFirstPos       = strSqlQuery.IndexOf( "AND", 0 );
            string  strFirstPart    = strSqlQuery.Substring( 0, iFirstPos );
            string  strSecondPart   = strSqlQuery.Substring( iFirstPos + 3, strSqlQuery.Length - iFirstPos - 3 );

            strFinalString  = strFirstPart + strSecondPart;
        }


        strFinalString  += " ORDER BY CAST( WRNT_Warranty_No AS INT ) DESC ";

        return  GetRows( strFinalString, strCountQuery, CreateParameterArray( objWarrantyFilter ), CommandType.Text, null, e );
    }
```

Comment: Added. Let me know, if I should post code for some other function.

Comment: @jitendragarg So what's the real problem - you can't get the value of the textbox, or you wonder how the textbox is magically populated when the value is not in the query string?

Comment: I can't seem to access the value. It is an update screen. On postback, I use the textbox value to ensure that record exists, before I modify it. `rowWarranty[ "WRNT_Warranty_No" ] = txtWarrantyNoValue.Text.Trim();` This code used to work earlier, and works well in other pages, but here it says text value is empty string.

Comment: From what I see you are using `Web Forms` and in `Web Forms` the data persistence is achieved through `ViewState` so if you want to persist the value of any control for whatever reason you can use the `ViewState` for this. As you have noticed, the framework is taking care for this by it's own but you get the value when the page was submitted. The solution - just set the property of the asp control on postback but be aware that the `ViewState` (where your data is persisted) is not accessable on `Page_Load` event!

Comment: Wait, I am supposed to do the opposite. I have to set the value on page load, so that I can use it during post back. I can't add the value to viewstate manually, as it is inaccessible during page load. Also, just to be on same page, this same code works well on .net 1.0. We recently upgraded it, and VS2014 moved all the binding events to designer files. It is possible that might have caused problem (although it happens in only few pages).

Comment: The exact solution depends on your actual programming logic. Now it's getting clear that you are migrating a project so I suggest you to repost the question trying to define better what's the problem and what are the circumstances. The way I'm dealing with this is - on the `click` event of the button or whatever event you use to get to the code behind you save the values you want in `ViewState["youControlValue"]` but and then if you are doing full post back just use some of the other events. Just google on which events ViewState is accessable and use any of those.

Comment: So to make it clear, if you want to persist some data on your own. When you are on the view and click say - `btnSubmit` then on your code behind in the `btnSubmit_Click()` event you save the value in thew viewstate like so - `ViewState["someControl"] = hiddenField.Value;` then I think on `OnPreLoad(EventArgs e)` you make something like `hiddenField.Value = ViewState["SomeControl"].ToString()` and that's it. But I'm not sure you need this so I leave it as a comment.

Comment: Ok. I tried as you suggested, but no luck. The page doesn't save the value on postback for any control.

Comment: Hmm, so post some code, because what I've decribed is working for me. Change your code and show how and where you save the value of the textbox and where and how you reassign it again.

Comment: Weirdest thing is happening here. Upon further inspection, it turns out '   rowFilter[ "WRNT_Warranty_No" ] = Request.QueryString[ "WRNT_Warranty_No" ];' is returning the value null. rowFilter is just a custom data type based on hashtable. Debug mode gives me `enumeration yielded no result` error when I try to see the querystring data.

Comment: In my opinion you are heavily misuisng the `QuerySTring`. You can start from here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx. If you want to pass complex data through the HTTP you need to serilize/deserilize it and I don't see something similar in your code. It might be better to ask someone in the office why you're getting this result.

Comment: I am not sure how you are getting at it. I am just passing a string variable. rowFilter hashtable is used just to store the 2-3 strings  received from the querystring. Say, querystring is like `x=abc&y=def&z=ghi`. then, rowFilter just save 3 keys, x, y, z with their respective value; instead of creating 3 different string variables.

Comment: So you have some datastructure where you save data passed with the QueryString and you expect to get this data back on postback. Tell me how do you think this will happen when in it's nature the http is stateless or in other words between two page renders you lose all your data?

Comment: Boss, I think I was not clear enough. I save the data passed by querystring after the postback. This data is used for some calculations and db queries. I save and use the data in the same page renders. Actually, you know, forget what I am doing with the data. Point is, I receive my url as "abc.com/xyz.aspx" instead of "abc.com/xyz.aspx?x=123&y=234&z=345". That is the problem. Browser shows the querystring, but it is not transferred to the server call.

Comment: So we are back again on the topic how exactly the QueryString works. It passes data in several ways, have checked here - `Request.UrlReferrer.Query` and also, at the end you might need to add them each time.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `ViewState[""]` or `SessionState[""]`. That will work fine for you.

Comment: I have enabled viewstate in the page attributes. What next?

Answer (score 0):

Use `if(!IsPostBack)` in page load event

```
   if(!IspostBack)
   {
      //Your code goes here
   }
```

write all codes inside of condition it will be fine.

Comment: its better to edit existing answer rather than posting new one.